# com.android.volley.noconnectionerror java.net.socketexception socket failed eperm EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android-studio

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Android 3.5

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)